# Turn dat file into matrix, include empty spaces

Tags: c#, matrix, text

I have a dat file that looks like this:

[image: this]

and I would like to turn this data into a matrix of some sort that includes values for the empty spaces. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Is the .dat file in fact plain text?

Comment: how can i tell if its just plain text? notepad displays it all crunched together with only spaces but notepad++ shows it more organized with columns and rows.

Comment: Sounds like it has tabs as separators. Try opening it in a hex editor (there is a plugin for N++) and seeing if 0x09 (tab) is present. But the fact that you can open and read it in notepad means it's plain text.

Comment: I couldnt find any matches. It looks like this http://i.imgur.com/Gb54ERH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to preserve the empty spaces then you may need to treat the data as fixed width columns.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27782/how-to-read-fixed-width-data-fields-in-net

If it turns out that the data is tab delimited as @WaiHaLee suggests then just split the lines using the tab character. For example:

```
//read all lines
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:/path/to/file.txt");

//loop through all lines
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    //split the line
    var splitString = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

    //pull out some data from the 6th column
    double avDP = double.Parse(splitString[5]);

    //save the data wherever you want
}
```

Comment: It's *not* tab delimited - see the comments above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't find any tabs in the hex code, as @WaiHaLee suggested i look for, but the fixed width column idea seems like a good idea!

Comment: @JohnCheathem - consider making this the accepted answer to thank shakinfree by rewarding then with a little reputation. You'll improve your own reputation too.

Comment: Thank you @WaiHaLee I'm still new around here. I hit the little check mark I hope thats how I do it